# 13.66 GB out of 15 Gb used in Gmail delete emails that consumed space

Tags: email, gmail

I have an old gmail account and I recently logged in I noticed it saying
[image]
https://one.google.com/u/0/storage?hl=en&utm_medium=web&utm_source=gmail&utm_campaign=manage_storage
how do I find out which emails have hogged all the space.

I want to delete all the un necessary emails which have consumed all the space.
How do I do this? Is there some tool that can do this I have forgotten which were important emails in this account I don't want to delete all the emails but I want to know how can I reduce problems in this.
I have only 90 such emails more than 5Mb
I am looking for some kind of tool that can help me with this situation.
Here is a screenshot of my email box
[image: 70K emails from various mailing lists and kernel groups]
70 thousand emails I have from Ubuntu kernel mailing list itself.

[image: other gmail questions by other users on stackoverflow]

Also read https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research. Here are a few suggestions on how to properly ask this type of question.

Comment: If you use a mail client like MS Outlook (or can), I've found it's a lot easier to manage your storage. You could connect your Gmail account to Outlook, wait for it all to sync, and then go in each folder and sort by size. Look for emails with attachments. If you're like me, you usually save the attachments somewhere, so you could free up a lot of space by selecting each attachment and clicking "Detach" or "Remove attachment". I've saved GBs of space on multiple accounts using this technique. This gets rids of what takes up the most space fast.

Comment: Can’t you just delete the folders? For example, just delete the “Ubuntu Kernel” folder.

Comment: Folder deletion will delete some important emails also which I should not delete I have to go through messages before deleting them.

Comment: To reword, remove "I am looking for some kind of tool that can help me with this situation" and replace with "I am looking for methods to resolve this problem effienctly" or words to that effect. Then votes to reopen the question can be cast.

Comment: @K7AAY I don't  care stackoverflow and associated websites have become troll websites.Almost all my questions get closed or downvoted.giving you links to check yourself all genuine questions were downvoted or closed by some one who thought it to be non sense 1)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59174570/find-gcd-of-2-numbers-in-c 2)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59094035/syms-requires-symbolic-math-toolbox 3)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58893497/anomaly-detection-in-cloud-computing-environments I ask questions on other forums also now a days I have learned to migrate from SO.

Comment: Yup. I can see you did not clearly state the problem you needed help with, and just threw code up on the wall, the way you threw screenshots up on the wall here. Folks who volunteer will often want you to get to the chase and be lucid, which I didn't see happening; you also posted here instead of in http://webapps.stackexchange.com where Gmail issues should go, Good-bye.

Comment: I did clearly state the problem within 30 minutes of me posting the code there it started getting downvoted Check this question https://serverfault.com/questions/994622/internet-connectivity-failure-in-virtual-machines-on-workstation all details given and 2 downvotes. I myself answered it later on.So most of the sties of stackexchange have become like that only read more here https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/) and configure it for IMAP connection to Gmail. Then you can pull down just the headers, find the emails to delete, and selectively delete them instead of having to pull down all the emails with POP to sort through them.

Comment: I have managed to configure thunderbird on a Ubuntu virtual machine now what exactly should I do if any tutorial link or youtube link you can give that will be great.

Comment: Configure it for IMAP connection to Gmail https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/thunderbird/emails-thunderbird pull down just the headers, find the emails to delete, and selectively delete them instead of having to pull down all the emails with POP to sort through them

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for all big emails you can just search

size:5000000

Which will find all emails bigger than 5000000 byres (~5MB)
You can also add things like date to narrow down your search more.

Comment: I searched after your message,there are only 90 such emails which are more than 5Mb

Comment: @Andreas Weigl Those big files will be the easiest to move and will save you nearly half a gigabyte so you can have time to find a way to move the rest.